# how do I create a tabbed activity with swipe views

Tags: android, xml

I am a bit new to Android programming so that's why I'm asking this, please how do I implement a tabbed activity with 3 views all with different titles. I know this would be really easy for some experienced programmers here. I have tried doing it a few times myself but failed miserably. I just want to know what basic things I should do to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: You can use ViewPager. Check this: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: Google a tutorial. After trying, if you managed to get some errors. Come back here and post the code you have so far. I'm pretty sure that the community would be happy to help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need-
1) Tab View
2) View Pager with Pager Adapter
3) Fragments to load inside View Pager

Check this documentation for more help -
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html